# Android : ImageView overlapping

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-relativelayout, overlapping

I have five ImageViews (ImageButtons) and I want to display this on one line, but when I'am on a small device my last image is cropped ?

How I can fix it ?

Is there a way to detect screen width ?

| A | B | C | D | E |

in my RelativeLayout xml file :

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mFooterProfileImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mFooterMembersImg"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_profile"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_profile" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterMembersImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mFooterCameraImg"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_members"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_members" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterCameraImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mFooterMediaImg"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_camera"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterMediaImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mFooterHomeImg"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_medias"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_media" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterHomeImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_home"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_home" />
```

Comment: You could use a **LinearLayout** and take advantage of **weights** to subdivide the screen evenly (20%, 20%, 20%, 20% and 20%). Also note that you `should` have **different** drawable folders, for each screen density, each one containing a pre-scaled image set. OR, provide the images in the largest density supported (scale appropriately) and let Android do the scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting Der Golem's comment as answer, just to help you. Use the following code in your xml to achieve your objective:

```
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height= "match_parent">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mFooterProfileImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"

        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_profile"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_profile" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterMembersImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_members"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_members" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterCameraImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_camera"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterMediaImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_medias"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_media" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mFooterHomeImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_home"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer_img_home" />

<LinearLayout/>
```

Hope this might help you

Answer (score 2):

the correct way to do that in my opinion is to create a linear layout,
make sure the orientation is horizontal.
then pass the layout_width="0dp" for each imageButton,
and also assign every imageButton with layout_weight="20"

this gives 20% of the width to each picture.

exactly like Der Golem said.

Comment: Yes. But you could also give a value of 0.2 for weights (which is intuitive). Or all 1 (well, android will correctly calculate the weightSum as 5 and say "each one of these wants 1/5th"). +1